# Question about bounded sequence with two sub-sequential limits.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you please give me some hint how to deal with this question.

Suppose $(a_n)$ is bounded sequence with 2 sub-sequential limits.
Prove : there are real numbers A and B that $b_n={a_n}^2+Aa_n+B\to0$.

I tried to write all facts than may be concluded :

If $a_1,a_2$ are sub-sequential limits of $a_n$ then there are $a_{n_k}\to a_1$ and $a_{n_m}\to a_2$,
therefore if $f(x)=ax^2+Bx+A$ then $b_{n_k}=f(a_{n_k})\to f(a_1)<\infty,b_{n_m}=f(a_{n_m})\to f(a_2)<\infty$.

If $f(a_1)\neq f(a_2)\neq0$ $b_n$ has two different sub-sequential limits and therefore diverges.

if $f(a_1)=f(a_2)\neq0$ $b_n$ $b_n\to f(a_1)=f(a_2)$.

From $f'(x)=2x+A=0$ we can conclude that for all $x_1>x_2>-\frac{A}2$ $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$ and for all $x_1>x_2$ $x_1,x_2<-\frac{A}2$ $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$.

And after all this I still could not understand how conclude that $b_n$ must converge to zero.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Suppose the two sub-sequential limits are $c_1$ and $c_2$. Now consider $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n-c_1)(a_n-c_2)$$

Comment: I suppose the limit is zero, but I could not prove it. Could you please explain ?

Comment: The absolute value will be less than one of $\delta_1(|c_1-c_2|+\delta_2)$ or $ (|c_2-c_1|+\delta_1)\delta_2$ for sufficiently large $n$